# Collision detection failing at low FPS (Andengine)

Tags: java, android, andengine, frame-rate

I currently have collision between 2 sprites working, using `sprite.collidesWith(otherSprite)`. The problem is when the FPS on a certain devices drops below 20-25 FPS, if the second sprite is moving fast enough, collision is not detected. Basically the gap between position at previous frame and position at current frame is high enough to skip detection. My question to you is: Have you encountered this before, and is there some kind of workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for dyamic collision detection. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/902170/752320) a good answer for that, with some links to help you out.

Comment: Thank your for the info. I'll have a look at those links.